# Launch MetaMask login window by JS

Tags: web3js, metamask

I have installed MetaMask extension for Chrome, then I saw ext icon at top toolbar. To login I will open it by click on the icon. There is a question...

**Is there a way to launch MetaMask window by JavaScript?** 
I want use my own Login button at web page to launch login screen.

[image: MetaMask login]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome extension popups like this can only be opened by the user triggering it themselves, either by clicking on the icon or a keyboard shortcut.

You could use the `ethereum.enable()` call they've recently added to prompt the user though: https://medium.com/metamask/https-medium-com-metamask-breaking-change-injecting-web3-7722797916a8. This may provide the type of user experience you'd expect.

Comment: No problem. Would you mind marking the question as answered by this since it worked for you?

Comment: This will be deprecated. Use this instead: await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });