# How to open metamask erc20 transfer window using web3 apis?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, metamask

In my frontend I have 'withdraw' and 'deposit' buttons. I want to display the metamask screen that comes after clicking on the deposit and send buttons (of metamask) when the user clicks on the deposit and withdraw buttons (of the frontend) respectively. So basically, the flow would be like - the user clicks on a button in the frontend say 'deposit' then the metamask pop-up should display the screen that would have appeared if one would manually click on the deposit button in the initial metamask pop-up screen and so on.

I'm not too sure if there is really a way to do so. If yes then kindly enlighten..

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't entirely understand your question, But please check if this answer can be of any help.
[Launch MetaMask login window by JS](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/62597/launch-metamask-login-window-by-js)